# Javafx 8 dialog extra borders

Tags: javafx, dialog, border

**Problem:** extra borders in the dialog, that I would like to remove.

**Description:** I created a simple application with a button that shows a dialog. I set an anchor pane with a green background as content of the dialog. This anchor pane contains another anchor pane with a black background and it's anchored to the parent in order to fill the whole space. In theory I should not see any green area, only the black one. But it's not, ther are like green borders.

Why? Thanks for your help!

[screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITrmB.png)

```
package testdialog;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;


public class TestDialog extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Show dialog");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            AnchorPane content = new AnchorPane();
            content.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green; -fx-border-color: red;");
            content.setPrefSize(100, 100);

            AnchorPane innerAnchorPane = new AnchorPane();
            innerAnchorPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: black;");
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(innerAnchorPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(innerAnchorPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(innerAnchorPane, 0d);
            AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(innerAnchorPane, 0d);

            content.getChildren().add(innerAnchorPane);

            Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
            dlg.getDialogPane().getStyleClass().add("customDialog");
            dlg.initOwner(primaryStage);
            dlg.getDialogPane().setContent(content);
            dlg.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
            dlg.initModality(Modality.NONE);
            dlg.show();
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

css file (style.css). The customDialog class is just to remove the button bar of the dialog.

```
.customDialog > *.button-bar > *.container {
    -fx-pref-height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default style sheet, [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) has the following rule:

```css
.dialog-pane > .content {
    -fx-padding: 0.833em; /* 10 */
}
```

which adds 10 pixels padding to the content of the dialog pane.

You can override this in your dialog with

```css
.customDialog .content {
    -fx-padding: 0 ;
}
```

in your style.css file.